# How to identify which registered fingerprint is authorized with android fingerprint API

Tags: android, fingerprint, android-fingerprint-api

I wanted to use Fingerprint authentication for one of my app for login. In my app, more than one user can do login with app. Now I want to implement Fingerprint authentication for ease of my users. I will need to differentiate the users somehow. So that I wanted to if I can know which fingerprint was recognized if I implement Fingerprint login. Is there any way to get any info related to fingerprints ?

Answer (score 0):

With Android it's only allow to verify current user against user of device.
You could create multiple users in Android but user need to select his user in Android before login your application.

There's some external fingerprint scanners compatible with Android Platform and with SDK for Android. These SDKs allow to enroll and verify multiple users.

Comment: How can I verify current user against user of device ?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0.html#fingerprint-authentication

Comment: @Bunny Is it useful ?

Comment: No Its not useful... There is no way to find out !